# Proving $V(x) = \frac{|y|^2-|x|^2}{|y-x|^N}$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^N-\{y\}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

$$V(x) = \frac{|y|^2-|x|^2}{|y-x|^N}$$

for fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n-\{y\}$

I need to prove that this this is harmonic. That is, the sum of its second partial derivatives are $0$. Let's calculate them.

$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)' = \frac{fg'-gf'}{g^2}$$

so:

$$\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x_j} = \frac{(|y|^2-|x|^2)N|y-x|^{N-1}\frac{(-x_j)}{|y-x|} - |y-x|^N(-2|x|\frac{x_j}{|x|})}{|y-x|^{2N}} = \\\frac{-Nx_j(|y|^2-|x|^2)|y-x|^{N-2}+2x_j|y-x|^N}{|y-x|^{2N}}$$

so

$$\frac{\partial^2 V(x)}{\partial x_j^2} = \frac{\left(-Nx_j(|y|^2-|x|^2)|y-x|^{N-2}+2x_j|y-x|^N\right)\left(2N|y-x|^{2N-1}\frac{(-x_j)}{|y-x|}\right)-|y-x|^{2N}\left(\cdots\right)}{|y-x|^{4N^2}}$$

where $\left(\cdots\right)$ is the derivative of $\left(-Nx_j(|y|^2-|x|^2)|y-x|^{N-2}+2x_j|y-x|^N\right)$. It has a product of three things, and another term. It's huge. Multiplied by the other things, it's even bigger.

I think this is not the right way to solve this exercise. Is there a better way? If not, how can I do these giant calculations by hand? It's too already in the computer using LaTeX.

Comment: Did you mean $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the product rule for Laplacian: $$\Delta(fg) = f\Delta g+g\Delta f+2\nabla f\cdot\nabla g\tag0$$

Here $f(x)=|x|^2-|y|^2$ and $g(x)=|x-y|^{-N}$. (I flipped the sign of $V$ to have fewer sign changes around.) So,

$$\nabla f = 2x\tag1$$
$$\nabla g = -N(x-y)|x-y|^{-N-2} \tag2$$
$$\Delta f = \operatorname{div}\nabla f = 2N \tag3$$
$$\Delta g = \operatorname{div}\nabla g = -N^2 |x-y|^{-N-2} + N(N+2) (x-y)\cdot (x-y) |x-y|^{-N-4} = 2N|x-y|^{-N-2} \tag4$$
where the last computation used the product rule $\operatorname{div}(\phi F)=\phi\operatorname{div}(  F) + \nabla \phi\cdot F$.

Stick (1)-(4) into (0):
$$
\Delta(fg) = 2N(|x|^2-|y|^2) |x-y|^{-N-2} + 2N|x-y|^{-N} -4N x\cdot(x-y)|x-y|^{-N-2} 
\tag5 $$
The rest is algebra. Let's put $z=x-y$, so $x=y+z$, and expand $|x|^2 = |y|^2 + 2y\cdot z+|z|^2$. Then (5) becomes
$$
\Delta(fg) = 2N(2y\cdot z + |z|^2) |z|^{-N-2} + 2N|z|^{-N} -4N (y\cdot z + |z|^2) |z|^{-N-2} 
\tag6 $$
which happily collapses into $0$.